# CSV string to decimal in python list

Tags: python, csv

I am using an API that returns what appears to be a CSV string that i need to parse for two decimal numbers and then need to append those numbers to separate lists as decimal numbers (also while ignoring the timestamp at the end):

```
returned_string_from_API = '0,F,F,1.139520,1.139720,0,0,20160608163132000'
decimal_lowest_in_string = []
decimal_highest_in_string = []
```

Processing time is a factor in this situation so, what is the fastest way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think the csv module is right here, I'd just use `str.split(',')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string by comma:

```
>>> string_values = returned_string_from_API.split(',')
>>> string_values
['0', 'F', 'F', '1.139520', '1.139720', '0', '0', '20160608163132000']
```

Get the values from string:

```
>>> string_values[3:5]
['1.139520', '1.139720']
```

Convert to `float`:

```
>>> decimal_values = [float(val) for val in string_values[3:5]]
>>> decimal_values
[1.13952, 1.13972]
```

Get min and max in the appropriate list:

```
>>> decimal_lowest_in_string = []
>>> decimal_highest_in_string = []
>>> decimal_lowest_in_string.append(min(decimal_values))
>>> decimal_lowest_in_string
[1.13952]
>>> decimal_highest_in_string.append(max(decimal_values))
>>> decimal_highest_in_string
[1.13972]
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks Doron!

Comment: You welcome. I think there some ways to make it faster but that requires some more information about the format. If the length of the values in the strings are constant you can use substring to extract the `1.139520,1.139720` part and split it. Thus not having to process the whole input.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way is to use regular expression. Readability is another issue..

```
import re

returned_string_from_API = '0,F,F,1.139520,1.139720,0,0,20160608163132000'
decimal_lowest_in_string = []
decimal_highest_in_string = []

re_check = re.compile(r"[0-9]+\.\d*")
m = re_check.findall(returned_string_from_API)

decimal_lowest_in_string.append(min(m))
decimal_highest_in_string.append(max(m))
```

Answer (score 1):

1) The version which does not rely on cvs

```
returned_string_from_API = '0,F,F,1.139520,1.139720,0,0,20160608163132000'

def isfloat(value):
  try:
    float(value)
    return True
  except ValueError:
    return False

float_numbers = filter(isfloat, returned_string_from_API.split(','))
```

2) try pandas package